# Update multiple tables : many-to-many relation

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

Need help in updating the tables

I have array of data coming from a form which I'm inserting in my DB. I have 5 tables

- product
- filter
- product_filter
- heater
- product_heater

Im able to put the data in the "product", "filter" & "heater" tables but i dont know how to put data inside the "product_filter" & "product_heater" table. Any help or direction to any tutorials is appreciated.

My Tables structure:

**product**

- id int(5)
- product text
- cost text
- details text

**filter**

- id int(5)
- filter text
- imgpath    text

**product_filter**

- id int(5)
- id_product int(5)
- id_filter int(5)

**heater**

- id int(5)
- heater text
- imgpath    text

**product_heater**

- id int(5)
- id_product int(5)
- id_heater int(5)

I want to have

- many-to-many relation between **product** & **heater**
- many-to-many relation between **product** & **Filter**

Here is the code :

```
PHP Syntax (Toggle Plain Text)
// Product data Update
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product']);
$cost = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cost']);
$details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);

$sql_title = "INSERT INTO product (
            id ,
            product ,
            cost ,
            details ,
            )
            VALUES (
            NULL , '$name' , '$cost' , '$details')";
if (!mysql_query($sql_title,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "records for product added<br />";         


// Filter update
// This is the array which is coming from the form
/*
    filtername
   Array ( [0] => ehiem 
            [1] => Hagan 
            [2] => Rena 
            [3] => jobo ) 

 filterimg
    Array ( [0] => img1.jpg 
            [1] => img2.jpg 
            [2] => img3.jpg 
            [3] => img4.jpg )
*/

$filtername = mysql_real_escape_string($filtername);
$filterimgpath = mysql_real_escape_string($filterimg);
$combined_array = array_combine($filtername, $filterimgpath);
$values = array();
foreach ($combined_array as $filtername => $filterimgpath)
{
    $values[] = "('$filtername', '$filterimgpath')";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO filter (filter , imgpath) VALUES " . implode(', ', $values);
//echo $lastid = mysql_insert_id()."<br />";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "records added<br />";

//Product Filter Update table
    // This is where Im stuck. Not able to even think of anything....


// heater update
// This is the array which is coming from the form
/*
    heatername
  Array ( [0] => ehiem 
            [1] => Dolphin 
            [2] => Rena 
            [3] => jobo ) 

 heaterimg
    Array ( [0] => img1.jpg 
            [1] => img2.jpg 
            [2] => img3.jpg 
            [3] => img4.jpg )
*/

$heatername = mysql_real_escape_string($heatername);
$heaterimgpath = mysql_real_escape_string($heaterimg);
$combined_array = array_combine($heatername, $heaterimgpath);
$values = array();
foreach ($combined_array as $heatername => $heaterimgpath)
{
    $values[] = "('$heatername', '$heaterimgpath')";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO heater (heater , imgpath) VALUES " . implode(', ', $values);
//echo $lastid = mysql_insert_id()."<br />";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "records added<br />";

//Product heater Update table
    // This is where Im stuck. Not able to even think of anything....
```

my question is : **how to update product_filter & product_heater tables** ?

Comment: how to update product_filter & product_heater table

Comment: what is the complete data coming INTO the form, and how do you want each bit of data stored into the tables? When you say you want many to many, you haven't actually given clues as to how this works - would the form on single entry lead to multiple entries into heater and product_heater, but only one entry into product?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it clearly. 
Yes you are right. single entry for product & multiple entries for heater are coming from the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting data into the product tables.
And you need to get the auto_increment_id of the products you just inserted.
This gets tricky if you insert multiple items.

However you have a single entry for the product, so that's easy:

Add the following after you insert your product:

```
echo "records for product added<br />";    
$get_product_id = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as product_id";
$result = mysql_query($get_product_id);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$product_id = $row['product_id'];
echo "product_id is: ".$product_id;
```

One way of getting the heater values is to add a trigger to your heater table:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_heater_each AFTER INSERT ON heater FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO heater_inserts (heater_id, conn_id) VALUES (new.id, CONNECTION_ID());
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

This will store all heater ids into a temp table, along with the id of the current connection.
This makes sure you don't run into concurrency issues where you use the inserts from other clients.

You can insert the `product_heater` table like so:

```
INSERT INTO product_heater (id_product, id_heater) 
SELECT $product_id, hi.heater_id FROM heater_inserts hi
WHERE hi.conn_id = CONNECTION_ID();
```

Don't forget to clean up the heater_inserts table when you're done.

```
DELETE FROM heater_inserts WHERE conn_id = CONNECTION_ID();
```

You can use temporary tables, which don't require cleanup and don't need a connection_id because they're unique per session, but in that case you need to create the table at the start of the session.
Also note that a temp table gets destroyed if the connection drops, so you'll need to add some boilerplate code to deal with that.

> *You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed. This means that two different connections can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table is dropped.) To create temporary tables, you must have the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES privilege.*